# How to enqueue javascript to wordpress child theme

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, wordpress

I seriously need some help before I loose my mind.

So I want to implement hamburger menu to my wordpress child theme. This one looks nice to me. https://github.com/joncoop/hamburger-menu

I downloaded the zip file, unpacked to to my computer tried it out, works like a charm.

I uploaded the files to my child theme, I did everything by the book.

Through my functions.php file I enqueued the styles and scripts appropriately.

This is the code I used:

```
function NovelLite_child_add_stylesheet() {
if (!is_admin()) {
wp_enqueue_style('hamburger', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . "/css/main.css", '', '', 'all');
}
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'NovelLite_child_add_stylesheet');

function NovelLite_child_wp_enqueue_scripts() {

wp_enqueue_script('hamburger', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . "/js/hamburger-menu.js");
wp_enqueue_script('neki', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . "/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js");


}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'NovelLite_child_wp_enqueue_scripts');
```

But it's just not working. main.css stylesheet is working fine, menu looks ok, it gets the hamburger button on mobile device, but when clicked, it doesn't show the menu. This tells me that javascript is not working as it is supposed to. So I'm wondering what could be the problem. I spent 3 days figuring it out and I am stuck.

P.S. Page source shows that scripts are enqueued!

Please help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the problem is in jQuery - your menu needs for it, but you're include it after hamburger js. Try this :

```
wp_enqueue_script('hamburger', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . "/js/hamburger-menu.js", array('jquery'));
```

to tell WP to load WP embeded `jquery` before `hamburger.js` and to use it for 'hamburger.js`.

Also if this works, no need to load external jquery here:

```
wp_enqueue_script('neki', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . "/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js");
```

But if you want to use your `jquery` file must change `hamburger` enqueue script to use your `jquery` file like this:

```
wp_enqueue_script('hamburger', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . "/js/hamburger-menu.js", array('neki'));
```

Comment: Thank you very much! First line with array('jquery') works. I also deleted second line which was loading external jquery. I actually think I tried this before, I don't know what happend then :) But in any case this worked great. Cheers!

Comment: wp_enqueue_script( 'theme-script1', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/main.js');
Is not working in my case. I am using in child theme.I try all the alternative.but no luck .
can you please anyone help me.
Thanks in advanced